# Visual Studio Not Displaying SVG image as background

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html, svg

I have a asp.net project with a html file(Html 5). I am trying to set the SVG as background of my body tag using the CSS 3. I have my file like this.

[image]

In my Style.css.

[image]

when i double click and open the html file. i can see the body filled with SVG, but this is not working when i debug with VS 2010.

This is what i got when i debug the html using the vs 2010.

[image]

Is any thing i missed here ? how to fix this ?

Comment: Have you verified in the network tab that the SVG file is being downloaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in Visual Studio web server only has a limited set of mime-types it can serve.  SVG is not one of them.

See here for a concise answer:
https://serverfault.com/questions/359904/how-to-configure-iis-for-svg-and-web-testing-with-visual-studio

Answer (score 8):

My workaround for this was to create my own httphandler locally which overwrote the content-type for svg.

```
public class SvgHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/svg+xml";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(context.Request.PhysicalPath));
        context.Response.End();
    }
}
```

and in web.config i added:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.svg" type="SvgHandler" />
</httpHandlers>
```

with this solution you don't have to use IIS express, you can just use the regular development server in visual studio 2010

Comment: Awesome, saved me some time and efforts. Thanks!