# Cannot display .svg files in Visual Studio 2012 (IIS Express)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, svg, iis-express

Im trying to display *.svg* files in my web application using *Visual Studio 2012*, *IIS Express v8.0* and *ASP .NET Web Forms*.

Things i already tried:

1. Adding .svg extension to web.config

> ```
> <staticContent>
>   <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
>   <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
> </staticContent>
> ```

2. Adding .svg extension to C:\Users\UserName\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

> ```
> <staticContent lockAttributes="isDocFooterFileName">
>   ...
>   <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
>   ...
> ```

3. Copy the URL of the image to the browser, and it's displaying fine.

[image]
 4. Publish the site under IIS, and it's displaying fine. Also, we have a developer using *Visual Studio 2013* and it's displaying fine using *IIS Express v8.5*.

Im adding the *.svg* as icons, using a `span` element with a class that has as background with *url* of the file, so i can't use this solution: [SVG files in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218235/svg-files-in-vs2012)

This is the style of class added to the span:

```
background: transparent url(images/svg/reports.svg) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px;
```

What's happening?

Comment: Did you make sure you can access the file by directly entering the URL to it in the browser?

Comment: Yes i did, im adding that information to the question!

Comment: @DiegoS Did you try the trick in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26385901/1429080). Seems like a bit of a hackish workaround, but might be worth trying out...

Comment: @user1429080 that did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based con @user1429080 suggestion, there's a workaround (altought is not the cleanest way it works):

> My workaround for this was to create my own httphandler locally which overwrote the content-type for svg.
>
> ```
> public class SvgHandler : IHttpHandler
> {
>
>     public bool IsReusable
>     {
>         get { return false; }
>     }
>
>     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>     {
>         context.Response.ContentType = "image/svg+xml";
>         context.Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(context.Request.PhysicalPath));
>         context.Response.End();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> and in web.config i added:
>
> ```
> <httpHandlers>
>   <add verb="*" path="*.svg" type="SvgHandler" />
> </httpHandlers>
> ```
>
> with this solution you don't have to use IIS express, you can just use
>   the regular development server in visual studio 2010

Source: [Visual Studio Not Displaying SVG image as background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575718/visual-studio-not-displaying-svg-image-as-background/26385901#26385901)